# SVN checkout fails/client freezes under Windows7 64-bits

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn, version, rapidsvn

I want to check out a SVN repository but it times out.
My environment is Windows 7, 64-bits.
I tried:
1) TortoiseSVN, a shell-integrated plugin,
2) RapidSVN, a GUI
3) Cygwin by using the commandline

```
svn checkout http://ticpp.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/
```

(I have tried other repositories so it is not that one in particular)
Note that the repository is browsable by simply typing the address in Mozilla Firefox.

Whatever I try it fails: app freezes and has to be killed. I cannot even browse the repository or view revision versions.

I have tried turning my firewall off but it did not help.

What could be the cause / what else should I try?

Comment: I tried a 
`ping http://ticpp.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/`
but it returns that the host cannot be reached.
Perhaps all SVN traffic is blocked; also it is my understanding that version control traffic uses the port 3690 which may be blocked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely you're behind a firewall/proxy that either blocks DAV requests explicitly or just drops them because it doesn't understand them.

Either configure your firewall/proxy properly, or try checking out with the https:// url instead of the http:// one. Most firewalls/proxies can then not interfere anymore.

Comment: https:// was successful, thanks for the tip :-)
As for firewall or proxy, I have little control over my organization's firewall..

Comment: Update your proxy informations in "global" section of "%appdata%\Subversion\servers" file.

Answer (score 0):

This may be caused by the SVN server. Try to report the problem to your server's admin in order to get help.

Comment: No it is not caused my the SVN server. I did mention that "I have tried other repositories so it is not that one in particular"